# What is the progress bar periodic update function return data?

Tags: 8, ajax

In Drupal 7 from the function called with 'url/to/call/progressbar/update/function' (see below) you would return an array converted to JSON like this:

```
drupal_json_output($message);
```

I cannot find any examples for Drupal 8 and I suspect it's an object rather than an array that gets returned.

Does anyone know how/what to return from the progress bar update function?

The setup for the bar progress indicator would be something like this:

```
$form['some_item'] = array(
  '#type'  => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('My action'),
  '#ajax'  => array(
    'callback' => 'a_function',
    'wrapper'  => 'ajax-response-goes-here',
    'method'   => 'replace',
    'progress' => array (
      'type'     => 'bar',
      'message'  => 'Starting...',
      'url'      => 'url/to/call/progressbar/update/function',
      'interval' => '1000'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core example is in [`FileWidgetAjaxController::progress`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Controller%21FileWidgetAjaxController.php/function/FileWidgetAjaxController%3A%3Aprogress/8.7.x). You need to return a JSON-encoded associative array with `message` and `percentage` keys. For example:

```
$progress['message'] = t('Uploading... (@current of @total)', ['@current' => format_size($status['bytes_uploaded']), '@total' => format_size($status['bytes_total'])]);
$progress['percentage'] = round(100 * $status['bytes_uploaded'] / $status['bytes_total']);
...
return new JsonResponse($progress);
```